# Microsoft Dynamics CRM Plugins

Tags: c#, plugins, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-online

I am New for Dynamics CRM. I entered into Plugins some of the scenarios using `LocalPluginContext` and `IServiceProvider`, I want to know the differences for these `LocalPluginContext` and `IServiceProvider`, and when to use each one please someone describe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically when you start developing plugin class library yourself in visual studio, you will go with basic skeleton along with boilerplate code that described in [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg594416.aspx). This uses `IServiceProvider` directly to get all context & services.

```
public class FollowupPlugin: IPlugin
{
        public void Execute(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
        {
            //Extract the tracing service for use in debugging sandboxed plug-ins.
            ITracingService tracingService =
                (ITracingService)serviceProvider.GetService(typeof(ITracingService));

            // Obtain the execution context from the service provider.
            IPluginExecutionContext context = (IPluginExecutionContext)
                serviceProvider.GetService(typeof(IPluginExecutionContext));

        }
}
```

Whereas CRM developer toolkit is an visual studio addin helps you to QuickStart Plugin development with templates. That gives you `LocalPluginContext` which allows easy access to the services provided by the `IServiceProvider`. It’s a wrapper on top of native classes.